# Reading from text file to array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read a text file in line by line and add it to an array, current code and output are below. How would I read it in properly, i.e. get the actual text to read into the array, rather than the current output. (Console App version of VB.NET)

**Code:**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim file As String = "C:\path\to\file\textfile.txt"
    Dim quoteArray As New ArrayList
    FileOpen(1, file, OpenMode.Input)
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        quoteArray.Add(LineInput(1))
    Loop
    FileClose(1)
    Console.WriteLine(quoteArray)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Comment: The output is correct because you are not printing the *contents* of the array.  But `ArrayList` is antiquated as are those legacy `File` methods.  Try `Flie.ReadAllLines` after you read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Not sure what was wrong with the question if i'm honest. Why not edit it to show me what was wrong? Also your answer provides no help as there is little context or explanation as to where to how to implement it. @Plutonix

Comment: @JackFinney What question?

Comment: @N0Alias I'm confused, what are you referring to? My reply to plutonix or the actual question?

Comment: I am not sure what you are whining about.  I did not DV your post if that is the issue.  As for context, programming *will* require that you do research - as the NET Framework is immense and we cant follow you around forever to fill in your gaps.  Type `File.ReadAlllines()` into the IDE, put the cursor on it, press F1 and Study.  As for the suggestion to read [ask] and take the [tour] - you havent as yet, so it is a good idea to do so, and I am loathe to post answers for those who havent. Ditto for posts that have been down voted. Have a good day.

Comment: I wasn't whining and if i'm quite honest I don't care about any DV's. I was unaware you could hit F1 and do such a thing in the IDE, so thanks. I was just confused and wondering what was wrong, as I have read the two links provided and added a slight edit to my post. The title is very vague because I am new(ish) to VB.NET and if i'm honest i'm not sure how to describe my problem, that's why it's been posted on here. @Plutonix

Comment: A) You *should* worry about DVs - enough of them will limit your ability to post.  B) the real problem is in printing not reading C) The IDE was also probably suggesting you dont use some of those legacy `Filexxx` methods - pay attention to it because it Knows Things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code works, but you cannot print an entire array at once. You've got to iterate the array somehow and print each item separately or combine them into a single string.

Printing each item separately:

```
For Each Item As String In quoteArray
    Console.WriteLine(Item)
Next
```

Combining them to a single string using `String.Join()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, quoteArray.ToArray(GetType(String))))
```

---

However what I don't understand is why you are writing in VB.NET, but are still using outdated functions and classes from the VB6 era:

- `ArrayList`
- `FileOpen()`
- `LineInput()`
- `FileClose()`

There are ***much*** better alternatives these days:

- `ArrayList` can be replaced by a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `FileOpen()` and `FileClose()` with a [**`Using` block**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) combined with a [**`StreamReader`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `LineInput()` with [**`StreamReader.ReadLine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or you can replace all the above with a [**regular array**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) and a single call to [**`File.ReadAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx).

1. **`StreamReader` solution:**

   ```
   Dim quoteList As New List(Of String)

   Using Reader As New StreamReader("C:\path\to\file\textfile.txt")
       While Reader.EndOfStream = False
           quoteList.Add(Reader.ReadLine())
       End While
   End Using
   ```
2. **`File.ReadAllLines()` solution:**

   ```
   Dim quoteArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\path\to\file\textfile.txt")
   ```

**Printing the list/array using a loop:**

```
For Each Item As String In quoteArray
    Console.WriteLine(Item)
Next
```

**Printing the list/array using `String.Join()`:**

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, quoteArray))
```

(if you are using the `quoteList` solution just replace `quoteArray` with `quoteList` in these two examples)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll have a go at implementing them. I'm using outdated functions and classes due to the way I learn VB.NET at college, we use quite an old programming companion (stupid, I know). I'll also have a go at using and researching the newer alternatives you added.

Comment: @JackFinney note that all the code you posted to read the file a line at a time can be replaced by that one last line of code.

Comment: @JackFinney : I linked the documentation to every new thing I mentioned. It is a good place to start reading (it usually includes examples too).

Comment: I missed it, sorry.  It;s **way** better

Comment: @Plutonix : Now, now... Don't mock my way of writing. ;)

Comment: @JackFinney When time allows, you should also up vote such an effusive answer.  Voting helps other users find good answers (up) and avoid wasting  time on bad ones (down).  It is how you can help others even if you cant post answers

Comment: @Plutonix I did upvote before but my rep wasn't high enough, I have now upvoted.

Comment: @JackFinney note that you can vote on any post you come across which you find helpful - not just those associated with your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines):

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.